# php dynamic table from muldimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic

can you give me idea how to implement this idea for "dynamic" html table.
I have an array

```
$arr = array(
  array(
       'label' => 'First name',
       'data' => array(
           array('fname' => 'John'),
           array('fname' => 'Ralph'),
       ),
  ),
  array(
       'label' => 'Last name',
       'data' => array(
           array('lname' => 'Doe'),
           array('lname' => 'Loren'),
       ),
  ),
  array(
       'label' => 'Description',
       'data' => array(
           array('description' => 'Something bout John'),
           array('description' => 'Something about Ralph'),
       ),
  ),
);
```

Now from the keys 'label' im creating the table columns

```
---------------------------------------
|First Name | Last Name | Description |
---------------------------------------
```

The problem is how to put 'fname' keys in the first column, 'lname' in the second and 'description' in the third.

With this part of code im trying to put the data in all columns

```
    private function tableBody()
{
    $data = $this->data;
    $table = '<tbody>';

    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        foreach($value['data'] as $k => $v){
            $table .= '<tr>';
            foreach($v as $col => $name){
                $table .= '<td>' . $name . '</td>';
            }
            $table .= '</tr>';
        }
    }

    $table .= '</tbody>';

    return $table;
}
```

Also my idea is not to hard code array keys for multiple usage(except label and data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would remap the data to process it in loops.

```php
$labels = [];
$rows = [];
foreach($arr as $column) {
    $label = $column['label'];
    $labels[] = $label;
    foreach($column['data'] as $key => $value) {
        $rows[$label][] = $value;
    }
}
```

Now print out the labels with the headline.

```php
echo "<table>\n";
echo "<tr>";
foreach($labels as $label) echo "<th>{$label}</th>";
echo "</tr>\n";
```

Iterate through the rows and create the HTML.

```php
$labelCount = count($labels);
$rowCount = count($rows[$labels[0]]);

while($rowCount) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $labelCount; $i++) {
        $current = array_shift($rows[$labels[$i]]);
        $value = reset($current);
        echo "<td>{$value}</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
    $rowCount--;
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

This gives a table like below

```
<table>
<tr><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th><th>Description</th></tr>
<tr><td>John</td><td>Doe</td><td>Something bout John</td></tr>
<tr><td>Ralph</td><td>Loren</td><td>Something about Ralph</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you. I had the idea, but I don't think I could do it.

Comment: Maybe there is a better solution, but I think the best is to have data in a form which can be easily iterated. So remapping is a readable way doing that in my opinion. At least it looks easier instead of dealing with an "uniterable" data set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manipulate the initial array to reduce it to something more manageable. You could brute force your way like so:

```
  function reduce($data) {
      $ret = [];
      foreach ($data as $d1) {
          // column header could have been fetched here
          foreach ($d1 as $k2 => $d2) {
            // keeping track of what label we need
            $key = '';
            // keeping the values together
            $child = [];
              // discarding non arrays
              if (is_array($d2)) {
                  foreach ($d2 as $d3) {
                      // identifier fetch from this level
                      foreach ($d3 as $k4 => $d4) {
                        $key = $k4;
                        $child[] = $d4;
                      }
                  }
              }
              // assigning back to the main array only if we have something
              if (!empty($child)) {
                $ret[$key] = $child;
              }
          }
      }

      return $ret;
  }
```

That will return the following:

```
Array
(
    [fname] => Array
        (
            [0] => John
            [1] => Ralph
        )

    [lname] => Array
        (
            [0] => Doe
            [1] => Loren
        )

    [description] => Array
        (
            [0] => Something bout John
            [1] => Something about Ralph
        )

)
```

Comment: i think i transform the initial array in similar form.